# Why node js telegram bot placed on heroku answer with 403

Tags: node.js, heroku, telegram-bot, telegraf, telegram-webhook

I write telegram bot and use Telegraf library.
I placed my bot on Heroku.
I set up webhooks this way:

```
app.telegram.setWebhook(`${URL}/bot${BOT_TOKEN}`);
app.startWebhook(`/bot${BOT_TOKEN}`, null, PORT);
```

But in Heroku logs I see
`at=info method=POST path="/bot" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=a8f99998-5e9b-4fe4-9af6-9ac56e492ae3 fwd="149.154.167.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=4ms status=403 bytes=101 protocol=https`

getWebhookInfo() also log `last_error_message: 'Wrong response from the webhook: 403 Forbidden`.
Trying test example from telegram webhook guide with postman also return 403

**SOLUTION**: I solved it by addition Express to my script like in this [example](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/44#issuecomment-269621948)

Answer (score 0):

The `403 forbidden` error code mostly happens if your bot has no access to what he´s trying to reach. An example could be that you called the `sendmessage` function with a **user_id** and not a **chat_id** or that your bot has no access to the chat (kicked/ banned).

As you were a little short on code, my answer could turn out to be not 100% accurate.

**Edit:** Here is a link to the [official telegram error documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/errors#403-forbidden) of the error. Maybe that could be of additional help for you.

Comment: I use chat_id everywhere. And with polling (locally) my bot works.
Also it's not completely clear for me - I think error from the side when telegram try to send me json, not when I try to write to user...

Comment: Did you ever try to host your script on another website then your heroku site? Alternatively take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

Comment: So it is the heroku configuration which causes the error. As I suppose that you can´t change that config, you need to find yourself another host I guess.

Comment: @AdaraHv Did you try to use another server/ host?

Comment: I've aready updated my question:  "solved it by addition Express to my script"

Answer (score 0):

A more relevant answer to this for Glitch users if you have setup everything else correctly: [Telegram 403 Error](https://support.glitch.com/t/telegram-webhook-doesnt-work-wrong-response-from-the-webhook-403-forbidden/42216/6) & [Ping blocked issue](https://support.glitch.com/t/api-post-from-one-glitch-application-to-a-second-fails-with-403-status-code/31510)